# R dbWriteTable doesn't work with a column of all NA's and class not logical

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi

I am trying to upload a table to SQL from R using `dbWriteTable` but I am having issues as some of my columns that have all `NA`'s in them. I've learned that if the class is logical than it works but if it is anything else, it throws me an error.

Anybody have a solution? The columns which will have all `NA`'s will be random so I can't just set a column `to.logical()` and I can't figure out a way to do it using `lapply`. I also do not want to get rid of these columns either.

**Works**

```
test <- data.frame(Name = c("Fred","Wilma","George"), Villians = c(2,4,3), Information = c(NA,NA,NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if (dbExistsTable(con, "test")) {dbRemoveTable(con, "test")}
dbWriteTable(con, name = "test", value = test, row.names = FALSE)

> sapply(test,class)
       Name    Villians Information 
"character"   "numeric"   "logical"
```

**Throws an error**

```
test <- data.frame(Name = c("Fred","Wilma","George"), Villians = c(2,4,3), Information = c(NA,NA,NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test$Information <- as.character(test$Information)

if (dbExistsTable(con, "test")) {dbRemoveTable(con, "test")}
dbWriteTable(con, name = "test", value = test, row.names = FALSE)

Warning message:
    In max(nchar(as.character(x)), na.rm = TRUE) :
      no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

> sapply(test,class)
       Name    Villians Information 
"character"   "numeric" "character"
```

I am using a company server so if there is any configuration that needs to be made on that end, I may or may not be able to get it done.

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning. Have you tried querying the table to see if your data is actually in it? (I just tested this on sql server and both frames inserted -- the second with the warning -- and queried just fine.)

Comment: You're 100% correct. Can't believe I didn't check that....

Comment: You aren't the first by any stretch :-)

Comment: However, note that your table structure will be different: in the first (no-warning) example, in sql server the column is of type `bit`, whereas the second table is type `varchar`. While the warning seems minor and/or annoying, realize that your future queries may rely on a schema (data-type) that is simply not the case if you are not explicit in your data-typing.

Comment: (In sql server and postgres, I think, you can use `"select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name='test'"` to see this. There's also `DBI::dbColumnInfo` mid-query before you `DBI::dbClearResult` (cannot use `DBI::dbGetQuery` for that).)